# How to get started with App-Tracking?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I've searched the web but can't seem to find any good information.

We are already working with GTM - GA combination for tracking our websites and now we would like to extend this to the mobile apps on both most popular operating systems (Android & iOS).

My question is whats the best way of doing this? I know our development team uses Firebase, but we really would like to use Google Analytics too next to the Firebase Analytics because our marketeers are used to GA. Any good courses about the GTM story?

The app will send datalayer objects trough firebase. The documentation from Google is quite abstract and doesn't specificly handle the GTM story. Abstract, especially if you compare it to the good documentation online about GA/GTM & Websites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start using Google Analytics [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) with server side code.

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers. This allows developers to measure how users interact with their business from almost any environment. Developers can then use the Measurement Protocol to:

1. Measure user activity in new environments.
2. Tie online to offline behavior.
3. Send data from both the client and server.

For Android, just do HTTP POST requests in Java. The following [Github Library](https://github.com/siddii/jgoogleanalytics) contains a Java Wrapper for it. A code snippet from the wrapper:

```
JGoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = new JGoogleAnalyticsTracker("Library Finder","1.3.2","UA-xxxxxxx-x");
FocusPoint focusPoint = new FocusPoint("PluginLoad");
tracker.trackAsynchronously(focusPoint);
```

For iOS, check the official [Add Google Analytics to Your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) Guide.